How to increase Glate app characters limit in ubuntu 22.04?

At present Glate app do Text to Speech (TTS) conversion in linux but
it has character limit of 5000. How to increase that limit ?


How did you install this app? If it is not in the official repositories, have you contacted the developers?

The snap store is not official repository maintained by Ubuntu developers, anyone can publish there. Please contact the developer of this app.

If you think this answer is correct click on the gray check mark ✓ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark your question as solved and help others.

A Google Translate Limitation
Glate is a desktop interface for Google Translate. This means it sends the text you enter there for translation or text to speech, to Google. Google does the translation or conversion to audio file and Glate presents the result to you. You can get the same results by visiting https://translate.google.com using a browser.
If you look at the bottom right corner of data input field on this web page you will see it has the character limit of 5000. You can see this in the screenshot below as 0/5000.

As a result, Glate cannot overcome this limitation.
Hope this helps
